# Static C-String is not keeping its value in a function (C++)

Tags: c++, static, c-strings

In my program, I'm trying to make the first run encrypt a password and the second run of the same function ensure that both passwords are the same (by comparing the encryption values).

When I do this however, it seems that `copyEncryp[8]` is not retaining the value of `encryp[8]`. When running the program, my compiler displays the `cout` statement for the `if` statement that the two C-Strings both match.

Am I not using the static variables correctly? As I understand, they are not limited to scope like normal variables and should be able to hold the same value the second time that the function is called. When trying to diagnose this problem, I thought that the fact that the declaration of the static C-Strings was called twice in succession (calling `password_encryp` twice) was an issue, so I moved the declarations into void function(), but then I got errors stating that the static C-Strings were not defined in that scope (error was at the first line where the encryption would take place. Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong here/is what I am trying to do even possible?

*I need to call the encryption function twice, the first time encrypts the first password and the second time will encrypt the entry for password, encrypt it, and then compare it to the copy of the first password encryption.*

```
void password_encryption(char password[8], int counter);

void function()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    static char password[8];
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> password;
    password_encryption(password, counter); //passing password and counter value
    cout << "Enter the same password for confirmation: ";
    cin >> password;
    counter = 1; //counter for the number of times that the function has been called
    password_encryption(password, counter);//invoked a second time passing user entered password and counter
}

void password_encryption(char password[8], int counter)
{
    const int key = 15; 
    static char encryp[8];
    static char copyEncryp[8];
    //loop encrypts password
    for (int i = 0; (i < 8 && password[i] != '\0'); i++) //loop for password encryption
    {
        if (password[i]+key> 126)
            encryp[i] = 32+((password[i]+key)-127);
        else if (i < 32)
            encryp[i] = password[i] + key;
    }

    if (counter == 0) //only runs first time
        copyEncryp[8] = encryp[8]; //making the first encrypted password copyEncryp
    if (counter == 1) //only will execute second time
    {
        if(copyEncry[8] == encryp[8])
            cout << "Both passwords match" << endl;
        else 
            cout << "Both passwords do not match" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not using arrays properly. This is an illegal array access

```
copyEncryp[8] = encryp[8];
```

because your array has size 8 so the valid indexes are from 0 to 7.

It seems to be quite a common newbie misunderstanding, if you put the size of the array in square brackets then it means 'the whole array', but it's just wrong.

Comment: So would the proper way to access these elements be done such as: encryp[0]? I tried just using copyEncryp=encryp; and got an error from that

Comment: @cmbtmstr You have two choices. The sensible option is to use `std::string` instead of using arrays. Arrays are very limited. The second choice is to stick with arrays but use a loop when you want to copy or compare two arrays.

Comment: For instance if you were using `std::string` then `copyEncryp = encryp;` and `if (copyEncryp == encryp)` would both be fine.

Comment: @cmbtmstr "So would the proper way to access these elements be done such as: encryp[0]?" - ehhhm, no. The proper way would not be hardcoding accessing index 0, but knowing that an array of 8 elements (starting at index 0) has valid indices in the range [0-7] and then accessing the ones you intend. In short; clear up  your understanding about array indices; they are *not* [1-8], but [0-7]. Index `0` is the *first* element, index `1` is the *second* element. Index `8` is *beyond your array*.